# Sql query to check if the expiry date is passed

Tags: sql

I am trying to select expired contract from my data base but is not working very fine please i deed help

It was saved in data base this way

```
pid   | name   | booking_date | expiry_date 
------|--------|--------------|-----------------
1     | home   | 2016-01-17   | 2016-11-11
2     | home+  | 2016-07-17   | 2016-10-03   
3     | home++ | 2016-02-17   | 2017-13-10


SELECT * FROM hostel_client 
WHERE expiry_date >= NOW() - expiry_date 
ORDER BY expiry_date ASC 
LIMIT 0,30
```

I need to output only expired contract `PID` 1 and 2

Comment: Surely you need where expiry date is less than now like this `WHERE expiry_date < NOW()` and loose the `- expiry_date` part

Comment: why the php tag? and which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: the php tag's been removed. You can see the answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- And above..... looks like someone is using `$comment->converToAnswer(`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788487/sql-query-to-check-if-the-is-passed#comment68799469_40788487`)->vampireThePoints()`

Comment: Yep, saw that @RiggsFolly I wonder if they'll have any marks left from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try less than `<` instead of greater than `>`

```
SELECT * FROM hostel_client 
WHERE expiry_date < NOW()
ORDER BY expiry_date ASC 
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: `$comment->converToAnswer(`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788487/sql-query-to-check-if-the-is-passed#comment68799469_40788487`)->vampireThePoints()`